# When I do a datetime.now() in Flutter, for example 1:7:6, it shows 1:7:6. We want this to be displayed as 01:07:06

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

When I do a datetime.now() in Flutter, for example 1:7:6, it shows 1:7:6. We want this to be displayed as 01:07:06.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

print('${now.year}/${now.month}/${now.day} ${now.hour}:${now.minute}:${now.second}')
```

result

> 2023/5/10 1:7:56

Comment: This isn't an appropriate way to generate date strings for users. Most of the world doesn't use that format. Let [`DateFormat`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) do it correctly for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now())
```

DateFormat documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html